# Blaze Persistence EntityView inheritance mapping

Tags: json, inheritance, blaze-persistence

I'm currently using Quarkus combined with Blaze Persistence for my microservice. I have the following entity model:

```
@Entity
public class Content extends BaseEntity {
    private boolean deleted;
    private boolean published;
}

@Entity
public class WebContent extends Content {
    private String webpage;
}
```

I've mapped the entities to the following EntityViews:

```
@EntityView(Content.class)
@EntityViewInheritance
@CreatableEntityView
@UpdatableEntityView
public interface ContentUpdateView {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    boolean isPublished();
    void setPublished(boolean published);
}

@EntityView(WebContent.class)
@CreatableEntityView
@UpdatableEntityView
public interface WebContentUpdateView extends ContentUpdateView {
    String getWebpage();
    void setWebpage(String webpage);
}
```

I have the following method in my ContentsResource:

```
@POST
public ContentUpdateView save(ContentUpdateView content) {
    return contentsService.save(content);
}
```

When I invoke the post operation I only get the base ContentUpdateView and not the WebContentUpdateView. Is there any configuration to do? (with Jackson I use @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubType annotation on the entities to accomplish this).

Thanks
euks

Comment: Hi, such a polymorphic usage in a JAX-RS endpoint is currently not yet supported. I created https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/1300 to track this. Would you mind commenting on the issue how your usage of `@JsonTypeInfo` looks like so we can better understand how you would like to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using Jackson annotation. Here's the base class:

```
@EntityView(Content.class)
@EntityViewInheritance
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DescriptiveContentView.class, name = "descriptive"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MediaContentView.class, name = "media"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WebContentView.class, name = "web")
})
@JsonTypeName("content")
public abstract class ContentView {
    @IdMapping
    public abstract Long getId();
    public abstract boolean isPublished();
}
```

And here's a subclass:

```
@EntityView(DescriptiveContent.class)
@JsonTypeName("descriptive")
public abstract class DescriptiveContentView extends ContentView {
    public abstract Set<LocalizedParagraphView> getLocalizedParagraphs();
}
```

I'm using abstract classes for other purposes, but it also works with interfaces.